# CSS - Making border box next to other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I tried making bordered box. I made new div, but the thing is. It will break "position" of my other box. Here's is an example:
[Normal looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKnGO.png)
[Example broken one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HPdc.png)

My question is, how could I prevent that? So, that other box would stay on the same place, but the other one won't just move to the direction where he wants?

Box

```
<div class="itemcart" style="
border: 2px solid;
width: 50px;
top: 80px;
position: relative;
height: 50px;
">Hello</div>
```

Comment: see how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here's a guess as you haven't provided your full code - add `box-sixing: border-box;` to the elements in question...

Comment: Didn't do anything. That's all code for the one box, other one got basically just white wrap and overflow-x